# Custom linear regression formula for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I'm trying to create a linear regression using geom_smooth, but with the formula 'Y ~ z1 + x2' as well as the formula 'Y ~ z1 + x2 * z1', but I can't find a way to visualize it using ggplot2

Here is the code that I'm running:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Data_proj <- read_excel("R/Test/Projekt 4/Data_proj.xlsx", col_types = "numeric")

y <- (Data_proj$y)
z1 <- (Data_proj$x1)/1000
x2 <- (Data_proj$x2)
z2 <- x2*z1

model <- lm(y ~ z1 + z2, data = Data_proj)

# Extracting fitted values and residuals
Data_proj$.fitted <- fitted(model)
Data_proj$.resid <- resid(model)

ggplot(Data_proj, aes(x = z1,
                  y = y, color = factor(x2))) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth() +
labs(title='Linear Regression model with 95% C.I', x='x1', y='y') +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
labs(colour = "x2")
```

Any idea how I can do it without using the built in R plotting package?`

Comment: See e.g. `sjPlot::plot_model()`, or the `ggeffects` package ...